# Get all visualsvn permissions for particular (user)SID from python WMI

Tags: python, wmi, visualsvn-server, wmi-query

I need to get all permissions for particular user in VisualSVN server by using the python WMI query.

Is it possible to get the permissions in a single query ?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade VisualSVN Server to version 3.4. The new release introduces PowerShell cmdlets for Subversion server and repositories administration and management. New cmdlets you are interested in are [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule) and [`Select-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Select-SvnAccessRule). Depending on your task, you could use one of the cmdlets to

- obtain a list of effective access rules on a particular repository path

  `Select-SvnAccessRule MyRepo -Path /MyProject/foo/bar`
- obtain a list of all access rules explicitly assigned for user account DOMAIN\username

  `Get-SvnAccessRule -AccountName DOMAIN\Username`
- obtain a list of access rules explicitly assigned for user account (its SID)

  `Get-SvnAccessRule -AccountId S-1-5-32-545`